# Developing RESTful clients on iOS

Tags: ios, restful-architecture

I am building an app on iOS and on Mac OS X that talks to a server using REST. The app is expected to store data fetched from the server in a local store (preferably in a SQLlite database). I understand using Core Data is a good option, but I am looking for an example of an app architecture that works on the basis of UI Views getting notified when the SQLlite database is updated as a result of a response from the server.

I have seen [a talk for Android at Google I/O](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xHXn3Kg2IQE) that addresses this type architecture in detail. Are there any similar talks/articles like this for iOS?

Comment: REST is the simplest architecture there is.  Each request to the server is independent.  REST does not even require a database on the client side, and who you want to notify when is entirely up to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mixing quite some different things here.First you need an interface for your restufl API. Look at [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) library to handle requests to the server and build your API handler. Then use an `NSFetchResultController` to listen to your core data being updated and do what you need accordingly in your views. NSFetchResultController is built to be used with a UITableView but you can use it in other situations if needed.

Comment: Thanks Nicolas. I think I will have to start small and take it from there.

Answer (score 1):

use [RestKit](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit) it's the best framework to work with Rest services. 
and it's well-documented. the latest version works on top of AFNetworking.

you can find some examples there as well.

Comment: Thanks Dmitry. I am looking at RestKit as well - but I would like to have as little 3rd party dependencies as possible in my project. Also, this forces me to really understand what's going on behind the scenes.